# Is ADT plugin for Eclipse still working in 2020?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adt

The process of installing the ADT plugin went normally until the *Add Android Preference* step where I need to specify the Android SDK folder which traditionally is at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk* .

The problem is the *developer.android.com* doesn't support *SDK Manager.exe* as a standalone package anymore but as *sdkmanager.bat* in their *Command line tools* package thus the SDK folder is different (Maybe *SDK Manager.exe* still exists as long as I install their *Android Studio* along but I  want to use *Eclipse* for Java IDE in general, not just Android development).

Previously the *sdk* folder contains these so Eclipse can locate the SDK component: (from instructables.com)

[image: tradition sdk folder]

But now there is only a *tools* folder and inside it are *bin* and *lib*.

Though I ran this code `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"` (then the *platforms* and *platform-tools* folder spawned outside the *cmdline-tools* folder) but when I add the folder *C:\android\cmdline-tools* (which is my ANDROID_HOME path and it contains the *tools* folder as required by the *Eclipse IDE* at the *Add Android Reference* step), the IDE gives me 2 warnings which are *SDK Platform Tools component is missing* and *Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK*. Thus the ADT will not work properly since it cannot locate the SDK components.

Maybe this is because the *Elcipse IDE* hasn't caught up with the *developer.android.com* yet or I am doing wrong somewhere? Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for several years now.

Comment: @greg-449 No way, there is the ADT plugin and tutorials on setting it up for Android development in Eclipse (though out-dated).

Comment: I think the Eclipse really hasn't caught up with the _android_ _developer_ _site_ because their way of locating the sdk components is really different from how the _android_ _developers_ organize their components now with their new _command line tools_.

Comment: The Eclipse foundation is nothing to do with the Android plug-ins, they are from Google. Google dropped Eclipse support in favour of Android Studio some time ago. Eclipse is not going to catch up, no-one is doing any development on the ADT plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks I believe that is the case now.

Comment: The AndMore project, https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore, was intended to carry this forward, but it hasn't had a release in over two years at this point.